# Simple Calculus with PDEs

Tags: calculus

Let

$$\begin{align}
   u(x,t)&=F(x+ct)+G(x-ct),\\
   u(x,0)&=f(x),\\
   u_t(x,0)&=g(x).
\end{align}$$

How can I show that

$$\begin{align}
   F(x)&=\frac12f(x)+\frac1{2c}\int_{x_0}^xg(s)\,ds+C,\\
   G(x)&=\frac12f(x)-\frac1{2c}\int_{x_0}^xg(s)\,ds+C\text{ ?}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the following:

$$
\begin{align}
u(x,0)&=F(x)+G(x)=f(x),\\
u_x(x,0)&=F'(x)+G'(x)=f'(x),\\\\
u_t(x,t)&=cF'(x+ct)-cG'(x-ct),\\
u_t(x,0)&=F'(x)-G'(x)=\frac{1}{c}g(x),\\\\
u_x(x,0)+u_t(x,0)&=2F'(x)=f'(x)+\frac{1}{c}g(x),\\
&\Longrightarrow F'(x)=\frac{1}{2}f'(x)+\frac{1}{2c}g(x),\\
\int_{x_0}^{x}F'(s)\,ds&=\frac{1}{2}\int_{x_0}^{x}f'(s)\,ds+\frac{1}{2c}\int_{x_0}^{x}g(s)\,ds,\\
F(x)&=\frac{1}{2}f(x)+\frac{1}{2c}\int_{x_0}^{x}g(s)\,ds+C.
\end{align}
$$

Equation $G(x)$ can be derived similarly.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** From the first three equalities you have

$$
f(x) = F(x) + G(x),
$$

$$
g(x) = c\,\Bigl(F'(x)-G'(x)\Bigr).
$$

Substitute these into the two expressions you have at the end.

Comment: That should be $f(x) = F(x) + G(x)$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael thanks.